# Java applet AccessControlException issue

Tags: java, applet, src, accesscontrolexception

I am having problems with my new Java applet.

```
 public Speler() {
     this.x = 10;
     this.y = 470;
     hitBox = new Rectangle( x, y, 52, 10 );
     spaceShip = new ImageIcon( "images/spaceship.png" );
}
```

In my project's src folder, I have some .png images which need to be loaded in. In Eclipse AppletViewer this works just fine, however in my browser it does not.

I have already searched the internet and tried signing it, however this didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated, however I just started programming in Java, so I don't know an awful lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
new ImageIcon( "images/spaceship.png" );
```

That constructor presumes the `String` represents a `File` path.  It cannot work for an applet from a web site since a `File` can only ever point to a resource on the *client computer* where the applet is running.

For an applet, instead access resources by `URL`.  The URL might be constructed relative to the code base or document base of the applet, or from a Jar on the run-time class-path of the applet.  If an applet is digitally signed and declares `all-permissions`, it can even reach across sites to fetch images, as long as the external site allows hot-linking.